# Is it possible to arrive in the US without a C-1 visa for a transit flight

Tags: visas, usa, transit-visas

I am from Peru. I have flight within 24 hours to Madrid and I do not have C-1 visa. I heard from some friends that they have entered US and paid for a Visa in the airport and did not have problems. I wonder if someone can share their experience or suggest a solution.

Comment: Of course, we understand from you question that you do not have any US visa at all. If you do have another type of US Visa (e.g. B-1/B-2) then you can definitely use that for transit as well.

Answer (score 13):

This is unfortunately not possible. The US does not issue visas on arrival, and the airline most likely won't let you board the plane without one.

Peru is also not a VWP country so you won't be able to use an ESTA instead of a visa.

Given how soon your flight is, you won't be able to get a visa in time so the only option is to change your flight.

Edit: as jcaron mentioned in a comment, any other valid US visa you might have can also be used for the purpose of transit, if you happen to have one.

Comment: There are few cases of visa on arrival, but forget it. Usually it is given if you arrive in US without visa, which should be impossible, but error happens. But you need to get the visa, and the airline is fined 5000$, so not a thing airline want to risk. Check this: https://thepointsguy.co.uk/news/arriving-in-usa-without-esta-staff-mistake/

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi ESTA is not a visa ('tho it behaves very much like a visa), and therefore everyone who arrives in the US with an ESTA arrives without a visa. That's a lot of travelers. Your second sentence should say "...if you arrive in the US without a visa or ESTA approval..."